# Syntax (probably BNF) spec of VBA ?

Tags: vba, syntax, bnf, language-specifications

I have to maintain a portion of Access 2003 VBA code, which is not my primary programming language, and while I'm pretty solid on doing regular stuff, I would still like to have a pure spec of the language syntax.. It just saves a lot of time compared to reading tons of stupid tutorials that tell me what a for loop is.

Is there any resource on the VBA syntax ? I would be happy to have it as formal as possible, probably something like BNF. I couldnt find an official spec on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Official reference is [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa296748%28office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Check out [VBA Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851%28PROT.10%29.aspx) (PDF) on MSDN.